# How to avoid getting "Property X of undefined" on page refresh while using NGRX selector

Tags: angular, ngrx

I've two feature modules(A and B), each with its own store, i dispatched an action of feature module A, from feature module B component and select the data from the store. But the problem arises when i refresh the page, i get an error "Cannot read property X of undefined", How can i solve this? or is there a way i can register a feature module entity to the root store.

I have tried to register the entity to root store and make it available at any feature module to use even on page refresh but i failed. (I'm using Angular V7.2 and Ngrx V7)

Comment: Have you verified that your store has state set for the given property? Did you set the initial state of the property in the store?

Comment: Show your code please